# RN CameraRoll gives uri as ph: //

Tags: react-native, ffmpeg, react-native-ios, camera-roll

Faced such a problem, I get a video using CameraRoll in order to later transfer this file to FFMpeg, but the problem arises in the fact that the path to the file is on ios using the ph protocol. How to be in this situation? How do I get real access to the file?